# laravel:5.7 Data isn't showing on page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have made a component in laravel and when I write some txt init, then it's not displaying, any solution to solve this issue,

screenshot of folders:

[image]

here what I'm using:

[image]

code of app.js  https://ibb.co/g4V12NF

code of users.vue:

```
 <template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Users Table</h3>

        <div class="card-tools">

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
        <table class="table table-hover">
          <tbody><tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>183</td>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>11-7-2014</td>
            <td><span class="tag tag-success">Approved</span></td>
            <td>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami venison chicken flank fatback doner.</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  export default { mounted() { console.log('Component mounted.') } }
```

can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: This is vue, right? Did you include the javascript and the component somewhere on your page?

Comment: CodeBoyCode here is code of app.js  https://ibb.co/g4V12NF

Comment: @CodeBoyCode yes i hv included <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> it at bottom but nthing happens

Comment: @Jerodev yes this is vue and maybe m wrong but  i hv run the "npm run dev" command to add js

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `asset('js/app.js')` for loading Vue code, correct way would be to use `mix('js/app.js')`, and don't forget to start your dev server: `npm run hot` or `yarn hot` (with hot code reload).

Also, you have to render your Vue app (you forgot that):

**`app.js`**:

```js
// ...
new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app'
});
```

Comment: followed it but same issue

Comment: @programmer0001 Show your initial HTML and app init code

Comment: master.blade.php   (paste.ofcode.org/su88Qqs9Zfis5nnyDhgwbE)        link of pasteofcode

Comment: @programmer0001 Updated my answer

Comment: this is complete app.js this code is already at bottom paste.ofcode.org/nB3ncdivdVfukaSKnfRW7J

Comment: @programmer0001 Still, your html code still uses `asset()` instead of `mix()`

Comment: changed it but still same error here is complete code can u plz see it //drive.google.com/file/d/1_SgPqv38MUyGDbQQph72TfDah7_q6GMZ/view?usp=sharing